# Database Design - foreign key same as primary key?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I would like if this simple database modeling is fine. Specially the Billing table.
Can you guys give your opinions?

[image: schema]

Comment: unless your foreign is unique , but you have to check i=on indexing issues

Comment: It is but it can more than one in one table. My question is if there is any problem in this model as my primary keys in EmployeeProject it is also foreign keys and the same case in Billing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking if it's ok for the primary key in EmployeeProject to consist of two foreign keys. If I've understood your question correctly, that's fine.

In Billing, there's nothing wrong with having a foreign key consisting of two columns that refer to EmployeeProject. (In SQL, `foreign key (empNo, projectNo) references EmployeeProject (empNo, projectNo)`.) You almost certainly *don't* want two separate foreign keys referencing Employee and Project here.

The three-column primary key in Billing (SQL, `primary key (billingNo, empNo, projectNo)`) allows data like this.

```
billingNo  empNo  projectNo  hoursBilled
--
1003       13     7          3
1003       13     6          2
1003       17     7          8
1004       13     7          3
1004       13     6          2
```

If that's your intent, you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks man. In case I wanted to have only one register of each in Billing, I would have to remove the billingNo right?

Comment: If you wanted only one row for each combination of empNo and projectNo, you'd remove billingNo from the PK.

Comment: Do you recommend for all PK in this table to be indexed - no duplicates?

Comment: If you're asking whether you should separately index each of the three columns in the primary key, probably not. But if you *do* need separate indexes on each of the three columns *in addition to* the primary key constraint, those separate indexes will *have* to allow duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly acceptable to have a foreign key column be part of the primary key of a table.  This happens frequently in **intersection tables** which implement many-to-many relationships, for example.

Some people find that is it preferable to use **surrogate keys** instead of compound keys.  When you use a foreign key column as a primary key you will almost always be using compound keys and these could potentially get large and complex.

If you search around here on StackOverflow and elsewhere you can find extensive and passionate discussions of the relative merits of natural vs. compound vs. surrogate keys.  If you read these you'll find that there are lots of people who would support the way you defined the primary keys in your model.